# choosing java ee web application framework

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, frameworks

I have studied making java ee web applications in my course.
For interface we used **html+css+jquery+ajax**
and for bindings we used **knockout**.
On the server side we implemented **restful services using hibernate,jax-rs,java servlets and filters.**

Now i want to make a web application of my own.but now i came to know about java web app frameworks like jsp/spring etc.
I dont know which framework we followed.*Kindly let me know which approach/framework used*.
And **would it be better to use a java frameworks rather than this approach** if yes then **suggest some good framework for my app idea.**
My web application is a voting site where you can vote and rate for any product.you can also do commenting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aim seem to be to form another **web shop with Java**. To make it happen easily and with high level of quality, I would prefer ready, open source (=free) web shop framework, like **Konakart** [[1]](http://www.konakart.com/konakart/Welcome.action).

It has all the parts of a web shop you need and administration of the shop is easy with UI, you don't need to code everything yourself, like Spring approach would need.

You can change the style of konakart to your own, so this I think would be ideal to start with. You don't have to invent every wheel yourself from the very beginning, so I would prefer this kind of open source possibility.

---

**Sources:**

[1] http://www.konakart.com/konakart/Welcome.action

Comment: thanks alot :)  can you tell me about the approach that we followed in our course.?

Answer (score 0):

There are many java ee web framework which by the end they all have the same purpose. It all depends which one you feel more comfortable to develop, study the examples and analyze the one looks easier for you to understand.

Here is a list of a few web frameworks that are popular:

- [Spring MVC](http://www.springsource.org/features/modern-web)
- [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/)
- [Struts](http://struts.apache.org/)
- [JSF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html)